# how to read cout/debug traces on a jailbreak iphone , while testing on the device

Tags: iphone, ios, console, jailbreak

What's the proper way to read console logs (messages generated from std::cout) while running your app on an iphone ?

Are there some commands enabling this, when you ssh on the phone ?

update @tanvir:
are you sure of the file? can't find a syslog file there.

Comment: can you not connect with the usb cable?  just connect, open xcode, goto Organizer, devices, pick your iPhone and view the **Console** output.  same as non-jb device.

Answer (score 1):

Install syslogd from Cydia. Once you install it and some SSH client, you should be able to run:

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a software `Log Police`. This will show system log directly and its free.